# Purchase Order entry screen and database design - PHP, db

Tags: php, user-interface, database-design, purchase-order

I'm developing a php/mysql purchase order system and need some advice on how to approach the user interface. I'm learning and figuring things out as I go.

So when a user is entering line items into a purchase order it seems like right now they would be entering the item and quantity into a form text field and pressing the submit button. Then my php would sanitize and process the item into the database tables.

The php would then send out a new page with the updated line item.

It seems to me that this is fine for a basic method but there should be more elegant solutions. I haven't learned much javascript yet but I can imagine a script that would prompt a php script to do the sanitization and insertion and respond with the new position item and cost. This is beyond my abilities right now but I would be interested to know if that's the direction I should head.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to look up the following:

- jQuery javascript library - you need this for functionality
  https://api.jquery.com/

Under jQuery, you will need to know

- jQuery.ajax (look it up here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- jQuery.change (look it up here: http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- jQuery.html (look it up here: https://api.jquery.com/html/)
- jQuery.val (look it up here: http://api.jquery.com/val/)

After reading the above it should suffice to set you on the right path -- jQuery is awesome, take your time to read the docs and maybe some beginners tutorials! 
Good luck

Comment: So if I read you right - you're saying that the original HTML page served up by php would have your basic "line position form fields" in it and a submit and reset button. The jQuery would be used to programmatically duplicate those form elements as needed as well as populating them with data pulled by AJAX queries to a php script/db.

Some of those fields would be information only - I would not trust price data submitted by the client - but would be shown as information only. As well as the total, tax, etc. fields would be calculated by the php script confirming the submission of the order.

Comment: You are kind of correct... the correct approach would be to have the order selects or inputs on a change event and work your magic there. Either get the data from some hidden inputs or attributes like id or rel etc.